# Included youtube video not working

Tags: php, html, youtube

I am including a Youtube video in my webpage, this is the code:

```
 <div id="content">
    <iframe class="aftermovie" width="800" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/
embed/vjFA_UNSl9c?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
 </div>
```

The site is running in *localhost*, when I use Chrome to see the page I see the video but can't do anything, in Firefox everything runs like it is supposed to.

Comment: Are you sure you're on localhost and not, say, on a `file:///` URL?

Comment: i copied your code into a project and the video displayed in chrome just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes I am shure he know what the path is, I also can see the cover image, the problem is just that I cant press on play etc, its like I see a static image. And weird that it do works with you

Comment: What exactly does the URL look like? If @amaudbey is correct, then it's a problem with the path

Answer (score -1):

you need the http protocole in your src to make this work with chrome

```
<iframe class="aftermovie" width="800" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/B4bb69Moff8?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't know. That's the only solution i've found (tested with chrome on linux/crunchbang) :/